# How can I break down a categorical variable by percentage in a summary in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset from which I need to gather some very basic descriptive statistics from. The dataset is a set of observations from a group of people which I want to break down by race in a table e.g. x% white, y%asian, etc. (There is a column that delineates race by a numeric identifier)

So far, I ran

```
summary(dataset)

summary(dataset$race)
```

...and  while it gives me a breakdown in raw numbers, I need to have this in a table broken down by percentages (also for other variables). Does R have a native function that does this or do you know of a good library where I can do this?

The dataset has one column called "race_num" and another called "race_string" where the race_string is a factor datatype and stores the strings of the race ("white", "hispanic", etc.). race_num stores a numeric identifier. I'd like a simple breakdown like so:

```
White:  x%
Black:  y%
Hispanic: z%
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` is a great package to learn because it can help you so much with exploratory data analysis and also cleaning.

`tidyverse` loads in a bunch of packages for you, so it is a package of packages.  In this case it loads in a package called `dplyr` which has the function you are looking for called `group_by()`

Here is a brief example using `group_by()` on a dataset in R called `mpg`.  The example gives a breakdown on manufacturer, but you could use it in this case to group by `%white` or anything else:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3

head(mpg)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#>   manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class 
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compa~
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compa~
#> 3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compa~
#> 4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compa~
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compa~
#> 6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compa~

mpg %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    manufacturer count
#>    <chr>        <int>
#>  1 audi            18
#>  2 chevrolet       19
#>  3 dodge           37
#>  4 ford            25
#>  5 honda            9
#>  6 hyundai         14
#>  7 jeep             8
#>  8 land rover       4
#>  9 lincoln          3
#> 10 mercury          4
#> 11 nissan          13
#> 12 pontiac          5
#> 13 subaru          14
#> 14 toyota          34
#> 15 volkswagen      27
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The other function I used `summarise` is commonly used with `group_by` and creates a new dataset.  If you wanted to add a new column in your dataset just replace `summarise` with `mutate` which will create a new column.

Inside the `summarise` function your can also use other tools such as `sum` or `mean` and specify a column.  `n()` used in the example, gives you the total number of observations.

The 'pipe' character `%>%` is a nice tool to get the hang of also.  It takes the dataset or vector created or given on the left hand side, and makes it the first (or data) argument of the function on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `summarytools`:

```r
summarytools::freq(iris)

#> iris$Sepal.Width  
#> Type: Numeric  
#> 
#>               Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
#> ----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
#>           2      1      0.67           0.67      0.67           0.67
#>         2.2      3      2.00           2.67      2.00           2.67
#>         2.3      4      2.67           5.33      2.67           5.33
#>         2.4      3      2.00           7.33      2.00           7.33
#>         2.5      8      5.33          12.67      5.33          12.67
#>         2.6      5      3.33          16.00      3.33          16.00
#>         2.7      9      6.00          22.00      6.00          22.00
#>         2.8     14      9.33          31.33      9.33          31.33
#>         2.9     10      6.67          38.00      6.67          38.00
#>           3     26     17.33          55.33     17.33          55.33
#>         3.1     11      7.33          62.67      7.33          62.67
#>         3.2     13      8.67          71.33      8.67          71.33
#>         3.3      6      4.00          75.33      4.00          75.33
#>         3.4     12      8.00          83.33      8.00          83.33
#>         3.5      6      4.00          87.33      4.00          87.33
#>         3.6      4      2.67          90.00      2.67          90.00
#>         3.7      3      2.00          92.00      2.00          92.00
#>         3.8      6      4.00          96.00      4.00          96.00
#>         3.9      2      1.33          97.33      1.33          97.33
#>           4      1      0.67          98.00      0.67          98.00
#>         4.1      1      0.67          98.67      0.67          98.67
#>         4.2      1      0.67          99.33      0.67          99.33
#>         4.4      1      0.67         100.00      0.67         100.00
#>        <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
#>       Total    150    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
#> 
#> iris$Petal.Width  
#> Type: Numeric  
#> 
#>               Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
#> ----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
#>         0.1      5      3.33           3.33      3.33           3.33
#>         0.2     29     19.33          22.67     19.33          22.67
#>         0.3      7      4.67          27.33      4.67          27.33
#>         0.4      7      4.67          32.00      4.67          32.00
#>         0.5      1      0.67          32.67      0.67          32.67
#>         0.6      1      0.67          33.33      0.67          33.33
#>           1      7      4.67          38.00      4.67          38.00
#>         1.1      3      2.00          40.00      2.00          40.00
#>         1.2      5      3.33          43.33      3.33          43.33
#>         1.3     13      8.67          52.00      8.67          52.00
#>         1.4      8      5.33          57.33      5.33          57.33
#>         1.5     12      8.00          65.33      8.00          65.33
#>         1.6      4      2.67          68.00      2.67          68.00
#>         1.7      2      1.33          69.33      1.33          69.33
#>         1.8     12      8.00          77.33      8.00          77.33
#>         1.9      5      3.33          80.67      3.33          80.67
#>           2      6      4.00          84.67      4.00          84.67
#>         2.1      6      4.00          88.67      4.00          88.67
#>         2.2      3      2.00          90.67      2.00          90.67
#>         2.3      8      5.33          96.00      5.33          96.00
#>         2.4      3      2.00          98.00      2.00          98.00
#>         2.5      3      2.00         100.00      2.00         100.00
#>        <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
#>       Total    150    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
#> 
#> iris$Species  
#> Type: Factor  
#> 
#>                    Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
#> ---------------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
#>           setosa     50     33.33          33.33     33.33          33.33
#>       versicolor     50     33.33          66.67     33.33          66.67
#>        virginica     50     33.33         100.00     33.33         100.00
#>             <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
#>            Total    150    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>